# linux sed, do insert and append at the same time

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have a question about linux sed command. I just want to **insert** something before every line and **append** something after every line. And i want to do these things **at the same time**.

For example, assume `file.txt` is like:

```
1
2
3
```

I need to output:

```
hello
1
world
hello
2 
world
hello 
3
world
```

so I think the command should be like:

```
cat file.txt | sed 'i\
hello\
a\
world\
'
```

But the result is not right, *a* is not interpreted as sed command, do I need some delimiters here or did I do something wrong?

Comment: Please add some sample input and what you expect.

Comment: cat is useless. feed the file to sed command directly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should remove the backslash after "hello" and "world", so the command becomes:

```
cat file.txt | sed 'i\
hello
a\
world 
'
```

Having a backslash after "hello" joins "hello" to "a" as if "a" is another line to be inserted.

Answer (score 1):

Just keep it simple and use awk:

```
awk '{printf "Hello\n%s\nWorld\n",$0}' file
```

or if you prefer:

```
awk '{print "Hello"; print; print "World"}' file
```

or even:

```
awk '{
    print "Hello"
    print
    print "World"
}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -e 'ihello' -e 'aworld' file
```

or

```
sed $'ihello\naworld\n' file
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try this command:

```
sed -ri 's/(.*)/hello\n\1\nworld/' file.txt
```

**Explanation:**

- Using the regular expression option `-r, (.*)` will contain the contents of each whole line, which in turn is changed to `hello`,
- followed by linefeed (that is `\n`),
- followed by `\1` (which is the contents of the whole line, gathered by `(.*)`),
- followed by linefeed, followed by `world`.

Using regular expressions,  `.` is any character, `.*` is zero or more occurrences on the line, `(.*)` places the line into `\1`, as the first regular expression in `()`.

Comment: Though this might answer the question, please also add a short explanation what your code does and why it solves the initial problem.

Comment: Good point. Using the regular expression option -r,  (.*) will contain the contents of each whole line, which in turn is changed to hello, followed by linefeed (that is \n), followed by \1 (which is the contents of the whole line, gathered by (.*)), followed by linefeed, followed by world.

Or using regular expressions  . is any character, .* is zero or more occurrences on the line, (.*) places the line into \1, as the first regular expression in ().

Comment: Well done. I incorporated the explanation in your answer, so we can delete the comments.